# OpenCV PCA Compute in Python

Tags: python, opencv, pca

I'm loading a set of test images via OpenCV (in Python) which are 128x128 in size, reshape them into vectors (1, 128x128) and put them all together in a matrix to calculate PCA. I'm using the new cv2 libaries...

The code:

```
import os
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

matrix_test = None
for image in os.listdir('path_to_dir'):
    imgraw = cv.imread(os.path.join('path_to_dir', image), 0)
    imgvector = imgraw.reshape(128*128)
    try:
        matrix_test = np.vstack((matrix_test, imgvector))
    except:
        matrix_test = imgvector

# PCA
mean, eigenvectors = cv.PCACompute(matrix_test, np.mean(matrix_test, axis=0))
```

And it allways fails on the PCA part (I tested the image loading and all, the resulting matrix is how it should be)...the error I get is:

> File "main.py", line 22, in
>
> mean, eigenvectors = cv.PCACompute(matrix_test, np.mean(matri_test, axis=0))
>
> cv2.error: /path/to/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:2781: error: (-215) _mean.size() == mean_sz in function operator()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem is with the size of

```
np.mean(matrix_test, axis=0)
```

Its size is (128x128,) and not (1, 128x128). Thus the code below should work

```
mean, eigenvectors = cv.PCACompute(matrix_test, np.mean(matrix_test, axis=0).reshape(1,-1))
```

Comment: That did the trick...totally missed that, such a dumb mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can also put

```
cv.PCACompute(matrix_test, mean = np.array([]))
```

and the function computes the mean.

Comment: Good answer +1 this helped me a lot. I also found that `mean=None`, is equivalent to this solution. Cheers