# How to use the PCACompute function from Python in OpenCV 3?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.1

The `cv2.PCACompute` function worked well in OpenCV 2.4 using the following syntax :

```
import cv2
mean, eigvec = cv2.PCACompute(data)
```

The function exists in OpenCV 3.1, but raises the following exception :

```
TypeError: Required argument 'mean' (pos 2) not found
```

The [C++ documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4e2073c7311f292a0648f04c37b73781) is not very helpful at explaining how I should call it from Python. I'm guessing that `InputOutputArray` arguments are now also mandatory arguments in the Python function signature, but I am unable to find a way to make them work.

Is there a way I can call it properly?

*(Note: I know there are other ways I can run a PCA, and I'll probably end up with one of them. I'm just curious about how the new OpenCV bindings works.)*

Comment: If it helps, there was an old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567704/opencv-pca-compute-in-python) that is similar to this problem you faced, where the same (and other) solution were given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Simple answer:

```
mean, eigvec = cv2.PCACompute(data, mean=None)
```

---

### With details:

1. Let search PCACompute the source first.Then find [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/22496742b4f984c115b2c4339193cadbe14d700d/modules/core/src/pca.cpp#L351-L360):

   ```
   // [modules/core/src/pca.cpp](L351-L360)
   void cv::PCACompute(InputArray data, InputOutputArray mean,
                       OutputArray eigenvectors, int maxComponents)
   {
       CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION()

       PCA pca;
       pca(data, mean, 0, maxComponents);
       pca.mean.copyTo(mean);
       pca.eigenvectors.copyTo(eigenvectors);
   }
   ```
2. OK, now we read the [document](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cv2.pcacompute#pca-operator):

   ```
   C++: PCA& PCA::operator()(InputArray data, InputArray mean, int flags, int maxComponents=0)
   Python: cv2.PCACompute(data[, mean[, eigenvectors[, maxComponents]]]) → mean, eigenvectors

   Parameters: 
       data – input samples stored as the matrix rows or as the matrix columns.
       mean – optional mean value; if the matrix is empty (noArray()), the mean is computed from the data.
   flags –
       operation flags; currently the parameter is only used to specify the data layout.

       CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW indicates that the input samples are stored as matrix rows.
       CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL indicates that the input samples are stored as matrix columns.
   maxComponents – maximum number of components that PCA should retain; by default, all the components are retained.
   ```
3. This to say,

   ```
   ## py
   mean, eigvec = cv2.PCACompute(data, mean=None)
   ```

   is equals to

   ```
   // cpp 
   PCA pca;
   pca(data, mean=noArray(), flags=CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW);
   ...
   ```

Comment: Thank you, the fact that you had to pass `None` wasn't obvious at all in the docs, even those about `noArray()` :)

Comment: The document says  `mean – optional mean value; if the matrix is empty (noArray()), the mean is computed from the data.`  So,  just pass `None`.